# Excel VSTO Application_WindowActivate

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm developing Excel addin using VSTO and faced strange error when i switch beetwen windows - Application_WindowActivate event isn't fired. It is working only when i switch between excel windows not when i switch beetwen office window and  excel window for example. Event WindowActivate is working perfectly in my word addin.

Any Help ?

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WindowActivate += Application_WindowActivate;
    }

 private void Application_WindowActivate(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook Wb, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window Wn)
    {
        Refreshribbon();
    }
```

Comment: `WindowActivate` at Excel is different to `WindowActivate` at Word.
What exactly do you mean by switching between office and excel?
Which office version are you using?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem in PowerPoint. If you have 3 windows open, say Presentation1, Presentation2 and Notepad, `WindowActivate` will fire if you switch between Presentation1 and Presentation2, but will not fire if you switch between Notepad and Presentation1 (given that Presentation1 was the last active window before Notepad). It also doesn't fire if a presentation window is currently showing the backstage.